# Using HTML Validation Popups with jQuery Unobtrusive Validations

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC site that uses Data Annotations for validations and I'd like to get "free" client-side validations. Most simple ones work well and Foolproof helps me with more complex scenarios. All is good so far.

However, I'd like to tie into HTML5 validations with browser support. Specifically, I want to use the little popups for all of my client-side validation messages.

I've created a JSFiddle example here explaining what I want and am coming from: https://jsfiddle.net/4nftdufu/

The behavior I want to see is shown by the first form (`Foo`).

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFoo" placeholder="Type Foo Here" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Foo</button>
</form>
```

The second form (`Bar`) is essentially where I'm coming from. Note that I'm hooking into some Bootstrap validation behavior here (I found that CSS online somewhere in a blog post or some other SO question). Ultimately, this is not the behavior I want and I've not spent any time cleaning up this imperfect integration.

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="inputBar" name="inputBar" placeholder="Enter Bar here" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="Bar-error" aria-invalid="true">
        <p class="help-block"><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="inputBar" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></p>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Bar</button>
</form>
```

**How can I get my Data Annotations + jQuery Unobtrusive-driven validations to hook into these HTML popups for all validation messages when in a supported browser?**

Comment: Your first example is leveraging the *browser's* validation, not anything to do with bootstrap.  At least, when I run the fiddle that's what I see.  It happens because it sets `required` attribute directly in the input.  The second example is leveraging standard jquery validation.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531033/mvc-validation-data-annotations-are-not-rendering-correct-html5-attribute

Comment: @stephen.vakil Really? I had just assumed that was Bootstrap somehow driving it. I didn't realize such behavior was in browsers today! So, are there any good ways to hook my Data Annotation validations into that? Or is that a bad idea for some reason?

Comment: I've fixed my question to remove my incorrect assumptions about bootstrap. Deleted some text but also left some stricken in case others have the same assumption I had.

Comment: You cant. Using client side validation with `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` adds the `novalidate` attribute to your form so that HTML5 validation is not performed (because they do not work together)

Comment: @StephenMuecke If that's the case, can you please post that as an answer so I can accept it? If it's truly mutually exclusive, then I believe that is the real answer. If it's a duplicate of another question, then feel free to point that out so we can close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Its late here. Let me check if there is a suitable dupe in the morning.

Comment: No rush. Have a good night. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC's client side validation using the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files and HTML-5 validation do not play well together. The `jquery.validate.js` file in fact adds the `novalidate` attribute to your `<form>` element to disable HTML-5 validation using the following code

```
// Add novalidate tag if HTML5.
this.attr( "novalidate", "novalidate" );
```

If you want your messages to look like the browsers callouts, then you can always use css to style the  element generated by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`. When a form control is invalid, a `class="field-validation-error"` is added to the element which can be used for styling (adding color, borders, using the `::after` pseudo selector to add arrows etc)

Comment: Thanks. This isn't the answer I was hoping for but I do believe it answers my question in that the jQuery Unobtrusive validations are incompatible with the built-in HTML5 validations (which I had previously confused as being Bootstrap-related). Thank you for clarifying this for me!